# Conversion of a graph

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions

[image]

Attached above is a graph with rotor speed on X axis, altitude on Y axis and various All up weights, shown as a set of curves.Now for convenience assume all weight curves are parallel  of constant slope and equidistant (In this graph they are not)

Is is possible to mathematically rework this graph so that X axis has the All up weight, Y axis continues to depict the altitude, and the set of lines now become the rotor speed? It can be done by physically plotting points......but is there a mathematical method to do it?  If so what is the mathematical theory behind it, when is it possible to do such a conversion, and when is it not possible. 
Will be grateful for help.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to answer this question without an exact equation for these curves. However, if you did have this equation that relates these three variables, you can make this kind of graph by setting one variable constant for several different values and then graphing the two dimension curve that results.

Comment: @ sirch thank you...yes, the manual way of doing it is to use a plot digitizer, use it to get coordinates of all points and replot...thats what prompted me to think about it.....if we assume slopes of all weight curves are known and constant, can we derive the other graph mathematically...i have not been able to solve it